# PromiseKit in Linux swift project works not as expected

Tags: swift, promisekit

If you execute in Linux swift project something like:

```
import PromiseKit

func runAsyncAction() {
    firstly {
        executeSomePromiseFunc()
    }.done {
        getResult($0)
    }
}
```

`getResult($0)` will never be executed. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux swift project you need to use:

```
import PromiseKit
import Dispatch

func runAsyncAction() {
    firstly {
        executeSomePromiseFunc()
    }.done(on:DispatchQueue.global()) {
        getResult($0)
    }.ensure(on:DispatchQueue.global()) {

    }.catch(on:DispatchQueue.global()) {

    }
}
```

PS. Works on Ubuntu 16.04, Swift 4.2